# kotlin Unresolved reference: Class of the other library module

Tags: class, kotlin

I have a library module: libCommon ,which contains a kotlin class:

```
open class Stu {
    var name=""
}
```

Have a default application module 'app'  which api project(':libCommon'),
Then create a class AStu in the app:

```
import siger.common.base.Stu
class AStu: Stu() {
}
```

Then build the project, get the error:  Unresolved reference: Stu

But if change the Class Stu to java class, it gots okey.

How to make it with kotlin? Did i miss sth.?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the example project? I wasn't able to recreate it. It works fine when I check this.

Answer (score 1):

found the Reason: Miss

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

in the library module

Comment: What strange is gradle:4.0.2 miss it is okey, but in gradle:7.0, which got error after android studio compile.